# What function can I use to evaluate $(x+y)^2$ to $x^2 + 2xy + y^2$?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

What function can I use to evaluate $(x+y)^2$ to $x^2 + 2xy + y^2$?

I want to evaluate It and I've tried to use the most obvious way: simply typing and evaluating $(x+y)^2$, But it gives me only $(x+y)^2$ as output. I've been searching for it in the last minutes but I still got no clue, can you help me?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer is

```
 Expand[(x + y)^2]
```

> x^2 + 2 x y+ y^2

But I recommend you to look at the following tutorials.

- [Transforming Algebraic Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TransformingAlgebraicExpressions.html)
- [Putting Expressions into Different Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PuttingExpressionsIntoDifferentForms.html)

And of course a super tutorial:

- [Algebraic Manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AlgebraicManipulationOverview.html)

Also this palette maybe really useful: **Top Menu >> Palettes >> Other >> Algebraic Manipulation**

[image]

Comment: I've found it in the same time you answered. Haha

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Nope. [Vitaliy won by 6 seconds](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EBQNG.png)

Comment: @belisarius I feel Olympics spirit ;-)

Comment: [Congratulations!](http://youtu.be/TYJzcUvS_NU)

Comment: I knew the palette, I just didn't know the name of the procedure.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira This pallete is without `Collect` (see my answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9111/what-function-can-i-use-to-evaluate-xy2-to-x2-2xy-y2/9119#9119)

Comment: Anyone got any ideas why `Evaluate` is on this palette?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Maybe to evaluate sub-expressions? One can select self-sufficient part of expression and evaluate it leaving the larger context untouched.

Answer (score 12):

### `Collect`

Since it hasn't been mentioned (and one can interpret the question in another way) I'd recommend to use also `Collect` (it can be applied not only to polynomials) :

```
Collect[(x + y)^2, x]
```

> ```
> x^2 + 2 x y + y^2
> ```

In more general cases it would be handy to use the second argument in the form of `List`, e.g. `Collect[(x + y)^2, {x, y}]`.
Comparing it to `Expand` let's try `Collect` with `PolynomialForm` :

```
Collect[(x + y + z)^3, x] // PolynomialForm[ #, TraditionalOrder -> True] &
```

> ```
> x^3 + (3 y + 3 z) x^2 + (3 y^2 + 6 z y + 3 z^2) x + y^3 + z^3 + 3 y z^2 + 3 y^2 z
> ```

it collects terms with various powers of `x` only, while this expands terms with positive integer power in the expression :

```
Expand[(x + y + z)^3]
```

> ```
> x^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 x y^2 + y^3 + 3 x^2 z + 6 x y z + 3 y^2 z + 3 x z^2 + 3 y z^2 + z^3
> ```

### `Expand`

It could be useful to take a look at the second argument of `Expand` e.g.

```
Expand[(x + y)^2 + (y + z)^2, x]
```

> ```
> x^2 + 2 x y + y^2 + (y + z)^2
> ```

it leaves unexpanded terms free of `x`.

**Edit**

Let's add another functions which can also  expand polynomials ( they serve different purposes though ) like :

### `GroebnerBasis`

```
GroebnerBasis[(x + y)^2, x][[1]]
```

> ```
> x^2 + 2 x y + y^2
> ```

```
And @@ ( GroebnerBasis[(x + y + w + z)^#, x][[1]] == Expand[(x + y + w + z)^#] & /@ Range[2, 10])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

### `PolynomialReduce`

```
PolynomialReduce[(x + y)^2, 1, x][[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> x^2 + 2 x y + y^2
> ```

```
And @@ ( PolynomialReduce[(x + y + w + z)^#, 1, {x, y, w, z}][[1,1]] 
                                == Expand[(x + y + w + z)^# ] & /@ Range[2, 10])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 8):

You might also try:

```
Apart[(x + y)^2]
```

> x^2 + 2 x y + y^2