# Simplify the multiplication such as $a*(b+c)$ to $a*b+a*c$

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to solve this problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/help-me-to-solve-a-condition-from-an-equation-that-requires-many-reductions) but have to understand basics. Suppose I have a multiplication such as $a*(b+c+d+...+x)$. How can I multiply it to the result $a*b+a*c+...+a*x$?

**Trials**

> **[Not working]** Reduce[(a + b)*c]
>
> **[Not working]** Simplify[(a + b)*c] or FullSimplify[(a + b)*c]

Comment: Try `Distribute[a * (x + y + z)]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks plesae, make it into an answer. It worked? It is giving wrong result with `"Distribute[(a + b)*(a + b)]" `, why?

Comment: Or `Expand[a*(b + c)]`.

Comment: Your new example is explicitly covered in the documentation. You should read it.

Comment: There are many ways besides `Expand`, e.g. `PolynomialReduce[a (b + c), 1, c][[1, 1]]`. Take a look here : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9111/what-function-can-i-use-to-evaluate-xy2-to-x2-2xy-y2/9119#9119

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this has been answered in the comments, but just for the sake of having an actual answer..

```
Expand[a(b+c)]
```

or

```
Expand[(a+b)(b+c)]
```

Answer (score 6):

While covered by the comments and [another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16008/52), I would like to expand on this a bit.  The word "simplify" has very different connotations between what you intend and what *Mathematica* intends. For *Mathematica*, it means simply the least complex solution by [some measure](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html). This defaults to the number of subexpressions and integer digits, but it can be set to whatever you wish in an attempt to coerce `Simplify` to generate a specific form (or avoid others), such as this example from the docs

```
f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _ChebyshevT, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
FullSimplify[ChebyshevT[n, x], ComplexityFunction -> f]
(* Cos[n ArcCos[x]] *)
```

where `ChebyshevT` is being made more expensive than its alternative forms. I would also look at the [example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bnhtcjqmulci-di60se) for `Abs` below that. Using this definition, then, the suggestions of `Expand` make sense as it is not simplest (least complex) form.

Your use of the word simplify is very different. In assigning problems to students, we use the word simplify imprecisely, and what we mean is transform it into a specific form which is not necessarily the simplest in form. I think this is where the confusion lies; this is not what *Mathematica* means, but it may be convinced that it is correct.